# Laravel Vaidation (exact value from database sometimes with required always)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

```
public static $updatePaymentRules = [
    'issue_id' => 'required|exists:ws_issues,id',
    'payment_status' => 'required|in:0,1',
    'payment_mode' => 'required|in:1,2',
    'payment_amount' => 'required|numeric',
    'payment_date' => 'required_if:payment_status,==,1|date|before:today',
    'date' => 'required_if:payment_status,==,0|date|after:today'
];
```

For payment_amount i need something like that

```
 'payment_amount' => 'required_if:payment_status,==,1|numeric|sometimes|same_if:payment_mode,==,1:$payment'
```

Where

- $payment is variable and it will come from database
- payment_amount required when payment_status,==,1
- payment_amount should be exact of $payment sometimes only if payment_mode,==,1, i.e. Full Payment
- payment_amount should be Numeric

Thanks in Advance

Comment: if payment_status come from request or Database?

Comment: From Database Amount Field

Comment: are you on laravel 5.4 or older?

Comment: I am using 5.4.